# Error in IE11 when trying to show a bootstrap Modal via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

modal.modal('show'); is triggering an error in internet explorer while it is working in all other browsers
The Error is Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'

Note:This modal is called by more than one button and it needs to be updated every time which is why I am doing the modal reset.

On a side note, why is it that I have to clone the modal twice to do a modal reset? Is there a better way to do the reset?

```
var original_model = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    original_model = $('#my_modal_id').clone();
})

function show_modal(user_photo) {

    //reseting the modal
    $("#my_modal_id").remove();
    var myClone = original_model.clone();
    $("body").append(myClone);

    var modal = $("#my_modal_id");

    modal.find("#photo").attr("src", user_photo);

    // more code to update the modal ...

    // Does not work in IE11 : Error : Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'
    modal.modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/79ov9agq/5/ strange it seems to be working on jsfiddle but it wont on my live site, I am using BS version 3.0 on my site not sure it that has anything to do with it

Comment: Check your jQuery version

Comment: You might also want to try renaming it from `modal` to something else.

Comment: trying remaining form modal  to modal_ref but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this code to your `show_modal()` function after the `var modal` declaration:

```
if ($.browser.version > 9){
    modal.removeClass('fade');
}
```

This would require the download of the [jQuery migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

Comment: Now I am getting a new error Unable to get property 'version' of undefined or null reference. I am using the latest Jquery and it has to be working because I am using it to make ajax calls and it is working in IE

Comment: That's odd. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/#jQuery-browser-version2 It should work

Comment: I've updated my answer. It looks like this would require using the jQuery migrate plugin.

Comment: Its fine now, something was wrong in IE I just did a rest original settings in advanced tab it and works now. IE = crap browser

Comment: You probably had IE in compatability mode.

Comment: Probably, but it still strange why the exact same code was working on fiddle and not the site. In any case thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case you use compilation for your project (with webpack, for example), you might consider to install the current polyfill package, that provides ES5 compatibility

```
npm i --save core-js
```

or

```
yarn add core-js
```

Then to add at the top of your entry point of your project

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support